# Sequence in measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I need to prove the following:

If $\alpha$ is a probability measure and ${X_n \to X} $ a.e then ${X_n \to X}$ in measure. Show that the opposite may not be true.

Comment: Another way is to use Egoroff's theorem, or tu use the fact that $X_n \to X$ in probability iff $\frac{|X_n - X|}{1+|X_n - X|}$ goes to $0$ in $L^1$ together with dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Deven Ware : I don't understand what $X = \cap_N \cup_{n \ge N} X_n$ means when $X_n$ and $X$ are random variables. Can you give further details ?

Comment: @Ahriman, yes sorry I read this as a measure space when I saw the problem last night, I don't know anything about probability, so I've retracted my comment

Answer (score 0):

For simple, let $Y_n:=|X_n-X|$. We have 
$$P\left(\bigcap_{l=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{j\geq n}\{Y_j\leq l^{—1}\}\right)=1$$
by hypothesis, hence 
$$P\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^{+\infty}\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{j\geq n}\{Y_j>l^{—1}\}\right)= 0.$$
This gives that for each  $l\geq 1$, $P(\limsup_{j\to +\infty}\{Y_j>l^{-1}\})=0$.
This implies $\limsup_{j\to +\infty}P(\{Y_j>l^{-1}\})=0$ for each $l$, what we wanted.

For a counter-example showing the converse doesn't hold, see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely/149786#149786).