# Why is the typewriter sequence named as such?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

I refer to the typewriter sequence (see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/)
defined by:

$$f_n := {\mathbb 1}_{\left[\dfrac{n-2^k}{2^k},\dfrac{n-2^k+1}{2^k}\right]}$$

Just curious, why is it called "typewriter" sequence?

Comment: Because the supports of the functions "move to the right" and then "reset" in the same way that the carriage of a typewriter moves to the right and then resets.

Comment: A physical typewriter goes click-click-click to the right, one letter at a time, then bzzzzt all the way back to the left when you hit the carriage return.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  is it possible to represent this sequence of  function on a paper ? because  i am totally confused here.

Comment: @Grvsaini See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3519855/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  thankyou, for your answer.