# Typewriter sequence does not converge pointwise.

Tags: pointwise-convergence

I am wondering why does the typewriter sequence defined [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) on example 4 does not converge pointwise?

$f_n= \mathbb{1}_{\left [\frac{n-2^k}{2^k},\frac{n-2^k+1}{2^k}\right]}$ for $ k\geq0 $ and $2^k \leq n < 2^{k +1}$

Comment: I think this will help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412091/the-typewriter-sequence

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For $x \in [0,1]$ with binary representation $x_0 x_1 x_2 \dots$ what are the values of
$$f_{\overline{x_0 x_1 \dots x_{k-1}0}}(x), \ f_{\overline{x_0 x_1 \dots x_{k-1}1}}(x)?$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand your notation

Comment: $n=\overline{x_0 x_1 \dots x_k}$ is the integer having for binary representation the "digits" $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_k$ so $n = \sum_{l=0}^k x_l 2^{k-l}$.