# $\int|f_n|\to0$ but $f_n\not\to0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I recently came across the following question:  Find a sequence of integrable functions $(f_n)_n$ such that
$$\int_a^b|f_n(x)|dx\to0\quad\text{but}\quad f_n\not\to0\quad\text{a.e.}$$
I am unsure how to approach this question, and would really appreciate a hint.

Comment: Do you know the standard example of a sequence which converges in measure but not almost everywhere?

Comment: Have $f_n(x) = 1$ on a smaller and smaller subinterval, but make sure the subinterval walks around the whole $[a, b]$ interval.

Comment: A quintessential example is the [**typewriter sequence**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412091/the-typewriter-sequence).

Comment: If you are not insistent on the space $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ , then for Probability spaces, there are easier(to understand) examples . Consider a sequence of independent $\text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{n})$ random variables. Then their means(integrals wrt Probability measure) converge to $0$, but they don't converge almost surely due to second Borel Cantelli lemma. In any case, just talking about existence of such random variables require the notion of Product measures  and the Daniell-Kolmogorov existence theorem.

Comment: Take a look at [Does convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere). Also see [the typewriter sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412091/the-typewriter-sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try the following sequence of functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$:

$f_1=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}, \  f_2=\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}, \ f_3=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{3}]}, \ f_4=\chi_{[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]}, \ f_5=\chi_{[\frac{2}{3},1]}, \ f_6=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}, \ f_7=\chi_{[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{4}]}, ...$

Where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of a set.