Does convergence of integral over any subset implies pointwise convergence?
Let $\{f_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions and let $f$ also be a nonnegative measurable function defined on some measure space $X$ with measure $\mu$. Is it true that if
$$
\int_{E} f_n \, d\mu \to \int_{E} f \, d\mu
$$
for every measurable set $E$, then $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

Isn't https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412091/the-typewriter-sequence still a counterexample here. The convergence of integrals is certainly true as the $f=0$

Your hypothesis holds with just convergence in measure (instead of a.e. convergence) as long as the functions are dominated by an integrable fubction . In particular if the functions are unformly bounded and the measure  is finite. So expecting a.e. convergence is too ambitious.
