# Almost Certain Convergence Example

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

> Demonstrate by way of a suitable example that if $(X_n)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a
> sequence of nonnegative random variables such that
>
> $P({X_n} = 0i.o.(n)) =1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} EX_n = 0$
>
> then it is not necessarily true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = 0 a.c.$

I don't see how the above cannot be true. Wouldn't Borel-Cantelli imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = 0 a.c.$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Borel Cantelli lemma plays no role here. Note that $P(X_n \ne 0 \text { i.o.}) = 0$ would imply $X_n \to 0$ almost surely. But $\{X_n \ne 0 \text{ i.o.}\}$ is not the complementary event to $\{X_n = 0 \text{ i.o.}\}$.

Counterexamples can be found e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely).

To expand on the sliding humps example: Let $A_n$ be the sequence of intervals $[0, 1]$, $[0, \tfrac{1}{2}]$, $[\tfrac{1}{2}, 1]$, $[0, \tfrac{1}{3}]$, $[\tfrac{1}{3}, \tfrac{2}{3}]$, $[\tfrac{2}{3}, 1]$, $[0, \tfrac{1}{4}]$ etc.. We consider the random variables $X_n(\omega) = I\{ \omega \in A_n\}$.

Now every real numbers $\omega \in [0, 1]$ lies in infinitely many of the intervals $A_i$, so $X_n(\omega)$ assumes the value $1$ infinitely often. But at the same time, $\omega$ is also in the complement of infinitely many $A_i$, so $X_n(\omega)$ attains the value $0$ also infinitely often.

Comment: Would the first counterexample work here? I don't see how $P({X_n} = 0i.o.(n)) =1$ is satisfied.

Comment: The example with the sliding bumps works. Note that for every $\omega \in [0, 1]$ you have that $X_n(\omega)$ attains the values $0$ and $1$ both infinitely often.

Comment: Even for the third example, I don't see how both my conditions are satisfied. Could you explain this a bit more? I will give you the check mark if you just provide an explanation of how they are satisfied for the sliding bumps example.

Comment: I have added some further explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I may impose upon you again, there is one more problem that I have which is based upon me finding a suitable example of something.

Comment: To keep things tidy, you should open a new question with your new problem.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049800/existence-of-a-sequence-of-l1-random-variables) to my other problem.