# Existence of a sequence of L1 random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

> Does there exist a sequence of ${L^1}$ random variables $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
>
> $P(X_n\neq n i.o.(n)) = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} EX_n = -\infty$
>
> If your answer is yes, provide an example. If your answer is no, prove that no such example exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation is slightly confusing, but I presume you mean the probability that $X_n \ne n$ for infinitely many $n$ is $0$.

Take $X_n = n$ with probability $1-1/n^2$ and $-n^5$ with probability $1/n^2$.