# $X_n$ converges in probability but not almost surely

Tags: probability, measure-theory, proof-explanation, almost-everywhere

Consider the sequence $\{X_n\}$ given in Davide Giraudo's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely).

As is explained in the answer, the lack of a.s. convergence comes from the 
Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Another way of proving it is by using the equivalence $$X_n\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{a.s.} X\iff\forall\epsilon>0 \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bbb P(\bigcup\limits_{m\ge n}\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\})=0$$

and showing that for $0<\epsilon<1$ we have

$\Bbb P(\bigcap\limits_{m\ge n}\{|X_n-0|\le\epsilon\})=\prod\limits_{m\ge n}\Bbb P(X_m=0)=\prod\limits_{m\ge n}(1-{1\over m})=\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod\limits_{m=n}^N {m-1\over N}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{n-1\over N}=0$

**1.** Why can we say/conclude that by taking the complementary $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bbb P(\bigcup\limits_{m\ge n}\{|X_m-0|>\epsilon\})=1$$

**2.** I understand both proofs (with the exception of **1.**) but I don't see what $\Omega$ is and what kind positive measure subset $A\subset\Omega$ would satisfy $\Bbb P(\omega\in A : X_n(\omega)\nrightarrow X(\omega)\}\ $, where $X(\omega)=0\ \forall\omega\in\Omega$ is the limit variable.

Comment: 1) If $\mathbb P(A)=0$ then $\mathbb P(A^c)=1$...

 2) We don't care about what $\Omega $ is (the only thing important is that such a probability space exist)

Comment: @user657324 1) yes but why does it work for limits? 2) Yes but what if you had to describe it? Your comment is of no help at all

Comment: 1) I don't get your point ! $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{m\geq n}\{|X_m|>\varepsilon \})=1-\mathbb P(\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{|X_m|\leq \varepsilon \})=1-0=1.$ 2) You usually cannot describe it, especially when you work with stochastic processes. (sorry if it doesn't help, but it's hard to be more precise).