# Why a sequence of random variables that converges in probability need not be convergent almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Forgive me if this question seems stupid because I'm not very good with limits.
Please tell me what is wrong with the following approach:

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables that converges in probability to a random variable $X$
Then by definition:
$$\lim\limits_{n→∞} P(|X_n − X| \ge\epsilon) \to 0,$$
where $\epsilon>0.$

And we know that,
$$P(|X_n − X| \ge ε ) + P (|X_n − X| < ε)=1.$$

Applying limits,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(|X_n − X| \ge \epsilon) + \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|X_n − X| < ε) = 1.$$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|X_n − X| <ε) = 1.$

And hence,
$P({ \omega \in \Omega : \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)})=1.$

Where am I wrong?
Please note that I'm not asking for a counterexample and I'm asking where my proof is wrong.

Comment: Your error is in the very last step. You cannot just move the limit inside the probability. The reason for this is best illuminated by a [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149777/43949), despite your explicitly asking not to give you one.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Almost surely convergence is equivalent to, for all $\epsilon>0$,  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cup_{i=n}^{\infty} |X_i-X|<\epsilon]=1$$ which is much stronger than your result $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[|X_n-X|<\epsilon]=1$.