# different type of convergence of random variable with summation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, pointwise-convergence

I have the following problem: 
Let $\xi_n: (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathrm P) \to (\mathbb R^1, Bor)$ 
I need to find a connections between: 
1. $\xi_n \to \xi$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\xi_n - \xi| \lt \infty$ a.s. 
2. $\xi_n \to \xi$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|F_{\xi_n}(x) - F_\xi(x)| \lt \infty$, $\forall x$ of continuity of distribution  of $F_\xi$ 
What I try to do: 
1. Prove that first convergence imply almost sure covergence (it quite simple: $\mathrm P(\omega \in \Omega: \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\xi_n - \xi| \lt \infty) = 1$, then I say, since sum converge absolutely, we have $|\xi_n - \xi| \to 0$, and this is the definition of almost sure converge. 
2. Since $\xi_n$ converge to $\xi$ a.s., $\xi_n$ also converge in distribution, so $|F_{\xi_n}(x) - F_\xi(x)| \to 0$ 
3. What I can't proof, is speed of distributions converge. 
Did I choose the right strategy to proof the statement?
To the opposite direction ($2 \implies 1$): 
I can simply take a sequence from here: [Convergence of random variables in probability but not almost surely.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely) , it'll also converge in terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|F_{\xi_n}(x) - F_\xi(x)|$, but it won`t converge in a.s. sence and hence in terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\xi_n - \xi|$

Comment: I told a lie about $2 \implies 1$

Actual proof here: https://observablehq.com/@coballester/can-convergence-in-distribution-be-much-faster-than-almost

if we take sequence from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely summation won`t converge for distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First condition doesn't imply second, we need some kind of uniform boundeness. For example, let $\xi$ and $\psi$ be uniform on $[0, 1]$ and independent, and $\xi_n = \begin{cases}\xi,\ \psi > \frac{1}{n}\\
2,\ \psi \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$.

We have $\sum_n |\xi_n - \xi| < \frac{2}{\psi}$ (as there are as most $\frac{1}{\psi}$ non-zero terms, and each is at most $2$), so $\sum_n |\xi_n - \xi|$ converges a.s.

But $F_{\xi_n}(1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, so $\sum_n|F_{\xi_n}(1) - F(1)| = \sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Yeah, now I see it, thx!