# Difference between Almost sure convergence and Convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Hi I am writing because I have been trying to understand the difference between the two definitions for some time. According to Wikipedia the definition of Convergence in probability is:

A sequence ${X_n}$ of random variables converges in probability towards the random variable $X$ if for all $ε > 0$

${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }\Pr {\big (}|X_{n}-X|>\varepsilon {\big )}=0}$.

And for amost sure convergence:

To say that the sequence $X_n$ converges almost surely or almost everywhere or with probability 1 or strongly towards $X$ means that

$
\operatorname {Pr} \!\left(\lim _{n\to \infty }\!X_{n}=X\right)=1$

or

$
{\displaystyle \operatorname {Pr} {\Big (}\limsup _{n\to \infty }{\big \{}\omega \in \Omega :|X_{n}(\omega )-X(\omega )|>\varepsilon {\big \}}{\Big )}=0\quad {\text{for all}}\quad \varepsilon >0.}$

For me the two definitions are practically identical, so I can't understand what the difference is between the two terminologies.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The difference is technical and you can only understand the difference through measure theory.  Unfortunately , Probability Theory cannot be understood with intuition alone.

Answer (score 2):

Almost sure convergence is strictly stronger than convergence in probability. Perhaps an example of a sequence converging in probability but not almost surely might help you? See the first answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely) question for example. Heuristically, convergence in probability does not rule out that for almost every "event" $\omega\in\Omega$ a large deviation of $X_n(\omega)$ from the respective limit $X(\omega)$ may be observed for arbitrarily large $n>0$.